# Resources not found on a javascript project

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, resources

I've an issue.

I don't know how  to include some sources on a javascript projet with eclipse.
When i open my web page there is this error that is showed.

```
> GET myImage.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

So someone know how to solve this issue ?

Best regards,
Antoine

Comment: could you place your code by which you are loading your image and where you have put your image.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a base tag in the head of your HTML document:

```
<base href="http://www.rooturl.com/">
```

..and then just make sure that all images are linked relative to this URL.